# Write to terminal in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python

I am trying to show the changes in the command line in real time in my Tkinter GUI, I managed to create the GUI and integrate the terminal into it, but I cant bind the buttons with the terminal, my code is :

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess
import os
from os import system as cmd

WINDOW_SIZE = "600x400"
top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)

def helloCallBack():
   print "Below is the output from the shell script in terminal"
   subprocess.call('perl /projects/tfs/users/$USER/scripts_coverage.pl', shell=True)
def BasicCovTests():
   print "Below is the output from the shell script in terminal"
   subprocess.call('perl /projects/tfs/users/$USER/basic_coverage_tests.pl', shell=True)
def FullCovTests():
   print "Below is the output from the shell script in terminal"
   subprocess.call('perl /projects/tfs/users/$USER/basic_coverage_tests.pl', shell=True)


Scripts_coverage  = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Scripts Coverage", command = helloCallBack)
Scripts_coverage.pack()

Basic_coverage_tests  = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Basic Coverage Tests", command = BasicCovTests)
Basic_coverage_tests.pack()

Full_coverage_tests  = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Full Coverage Tests", command = FullCovTests)
Full_coverage_tests.pack()

termf = Frame(top, height=100, width=500)

termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = termf.winfo_id()

os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 100x20 -sb &' % wid)

def send_entry_to_terminal(*args):
    """*args needed since callback may be called from no arg (button)
   or one arg (entry)
   """
    cmd("%s" % (BasicCovTests))

top.mainloop()
```

I want win I click the button to see it printing the command in the terminal:

[image: GUI]

Comment: The outputs of `print` and the child processes go to standard output, which (if this program is, for example, invoked from an interactive shell) _is_ a terminal.  As it stands, the program already does what is asked.  This question is badly written, because what is _actually_ wanted is for output to _not_ go to a terminal, but to be captured via a pipe or pseudo-terminal and displayed inside a GUI widget instead.  There are tens of Q&As over on Stack Overflow dealing with how to do that in Python.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a late answer but I have your solution :)

instead of using

`subprocess.call('perl /projects/tfs/users/$USER/scripts_coverage.pl', shell=True)`

I used this

`os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 100x20 -sb -e command &' % wid)`